# После старта activity из фона не обновляются виджеты

Tags: android

Программа выполняет в фоне определенные действия, и запускается, когда соблюдается условие для старта. После запуска отображается *activity* где идет отсчет времени в секундах и небольшая анимация.

Если не ставить блокировку экрана, то все работает хорошо, но если поставить на блок, то в *activity* после старта не обновляется *textview* и *imageview* (анимация), хотя экран подсвечивается и смартфон вроде как просыпается.

Бужу так:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);
this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
.......}
```

анимацию стартую здесь же в `onCreate`:

```
.....
mAnimationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) ivAnim.getBackground();
mAnimationDrawable.start();
.....
```

и в `onCreate` запускаю *Runnable*:

```
.....
tvTime.setText("text");
myHandler.postDelayed(runTime, 1000);
.....
```

Стартую *activity* так:

```
mcontext.startActivity(new Intent(mcontext, Call.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

Пробовал различные флаги, типа `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, чего не хватает, или в чём ошибка.

Comment: попробуйте пернести код в onResume, Например. При блокировке экрана, пока она не будет снята, сверху всегда остается Activity блокировщика (LockScreen). Поэтому скорее всего onCreate у вашей Activity вызывается, но на перед она не попадает ,и onResume вызывается аж после снятия блокировки

Comment: Дело в том что Activity запускается поверх блокировки экрана, начинает светится экран, в общем телефон вроде как просыпается.